# if statement cased error in android

Tags: android

ok so after i put the if statement i get this error on the closing brakers
package com.example.mohhmed.king;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class l1 extends Activity {

    ImageButton ans;
    TextView text;

boolean check(){
    if (text.getText()=="")    
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.l1);

        ans = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(check()==true){

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
                else
    text.setText("اجابة خاطئة");
            }`enter code here`
            );<----- here
        }<----- here
    }<----- here
}
```

Comment: This `if (text.getText()=="")` is **wrong**. Use `if (text.getText().toString().equals(""))`, instead

Comment: Also, you don't need to write `if(check()==true){` extended. Simply `if(check()){` is enough. And what's all these `<----- here` you added?

Comment: at least you used `v.getContext()`, اجابة خاطئة = Wrong answer for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
boolean check(){
    if (text.getText()=="")    
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.l1);

    ans = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(check()==true){

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
            else
text.setText("اجابة خاطئة");
        }`enter code here`
        );<----- here
    }<----- here
}<----- here
```

should be

```
boolean check(){
    return "".equals(text.getText()))    
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.l1);

    ans = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(check()){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            } else {
               text.setText("اجابة خاطئة");
            }
    });        
}
```